# insert data on wordpress database with a foreach

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sql-insert

On Wordpress, i want to insert data in my database on a table i created for purpose, i'm using the global $wpdb and insert.
I've got many more data to insert, is that possible to insert a foreach or any loop inside my array?

Thank you in advance,
jean-Charles

```
global $wpdb;
        $name="JC";
        $email="jcdarocha@gmail.com";
        $website="www.jcdarocha.co.uk";
        $country="UK";
        $message="hello World";

        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->insert( 'my_table',
         array( 
                '$name' => '$name', 
                '$email' => $email,
                '$website' => $website,
                '$country' => $country,
                '$message' => $message
            ), 
        array( '%s', '%d' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  $wpdb->query and concat all data into a string

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO my_table (name, email, website, country, message) VALUES ";
foreach( $datas as $data ) {
  $insert .= sprintf("('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s'),", $data['name'], $data['email'], $data['website'] , $data['country'], $data['message'] )

}

$wpdb->query( rtrim($insert, ','));
```

Comment: Thank you Tamil for your help, but i still need to write by hand all the input... I was searching a way to build a loop :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    global $wpdb;
    $name="JC";
    $email="jcdarocha@gmail.com";
    $website="www.jcdarocha.co.uk";
    $country="UK";
    $message="hello World";

    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert( 'my_table',
    array( 
            'name' => $name, 
            'email' => $email,
            'website' => $website,
            'country' => $country,
            'message' => $message
        ) );
```